# Rationale of finding similar images

Tags: images

I was wondering what is the rationale of finding similar images, such as Google's [Find Similar Images](http://www.google.com/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi) among others? Are they using some AI algorithms? Any references?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called [Content based Image Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content-based_image_retrieval).  Generally, it's like the software they use to create and manipulate animated textures. Or software that analyzes fingerprints.

You scan the photo and look for distinct lines and features, measuring how far they are from each other and at what angles. Then you look through your database of images and see which images have similar metrics.